# Issue with Infinispan 7.0 - BeanManagerProvider NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: infinispan

I have a Infinispan cluster which worked fine with version 6.0.2 However, when I changed the API libraries to 7.0.3, and run my application, I am getting the following error. Can anyone please let me know what could be causing this?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceException: Map phase failed
        at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceTask.executeMapPhaseWithLocalReduction(MapReduceTask.java:665)
        at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceTask.executeHelper(MapReduceTask.java:501)
        at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceTask.execute(MapReduceTask.java:414)
        at com.maxis.bigdata.data.infinispan.InfinispanLoader.cloneTable(InfinispanLoader.java:151)
        at com.maxis.bigdata.extractor.RAWExtractor.createRAWAppends(RAWExtractor.java:262)
        at com.maxis.bigdata.extractor.RAWExtractor.loadRAWData(RAWExtractor.java:37)
        at com.maxis.bigdata.core.SDTMEngine.run(SDTMEngine.java:58)
        at com.maxis.bigdata.core.SDTMEngine.main(SDTMEngine.java:107)
Caused by: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from ip-172-31-4-157-23963, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractTransport.checkResponse(AbstractTransport.java:44)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.processSingleCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:381)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommand(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotely(JGroupsTransport.java:560)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:290)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl$3.call(RpcManagerImpl.java:347)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Problems invoking command.
        at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl$2.run(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:196)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/infinispan/cdi/util/BeanManagerProvider
        at org.infinispan.cdi.CDIMapReduceTaskLifecycle.onPostExecute(CDIMapReduceTaskLifecycle.java:34)
        at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.spi.MapReduceTaskLifecycleService.onPostExecute(MapReduceTaskLifecycleService.java:50)
        at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceManagerImpl.map(MapReduceManagerImpl.java:221)
        at org.infinispan.distexec.mapreduce.MapReduceManagerImpl.mapAndCombineForLocalReduction(MapReduceManagerImpl.java:94)
        at org.infinispan.commands.read.MapCombineCommand.perform(MapCombineCommand.java:74)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleInternal(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:97)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.access$000(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:52)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl$2.run(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:193)
```

Link to the question on Infinispan forum - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/251438

Regards